# What is the proper way to edit woocommerce assets?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to woo and php, but learning. The file I'd like to edit is

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assests/js/frontend/add-to-cart.min.js
```

Now I know going into the file and editing it is bad form, and that updating woocommerce will wipe out all changes later on.

So my question is how do I edit this script in the proper woocommerce format?

Do I deque it? But then how do I reque my own file so it always runs in time?

Is there a way for doing small changes to .js files, and a way for doing large changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look here:

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php

You'll see that the handle of the script is wc-add-to-cart.

So do this:

```
wp_dequeue_script('wc-add-to-cart');
wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ). '/js/my-add-to-cart.js' , array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
```

Comment: I had found this and tried it before. But I made the mistake of placing my .js file in the woo/assests/js/frontend/ folder instead of the theme/js/ folder